# Reject git merges by branch name prefix

Tags: git, git-merge, git-config

How can I configure my git repository to reject all merge responses when the current branch name have a specific prefix?

I would like to preserve my master branch against merges from branches that are spike solutions which have a prefix like 'spike_'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer here is both no and yes, depending on several things that you did not specify.

Consider how commits—merges and non-merges alike—arrive in your repository:

- you can make them yourself;
- you can bring them in with `git fetch`; and
- you can acquire them via `git push`.

For the first case, you can write hooks or front-end commands that sit between you and `git merge`, but of course you can also bypass those.

For the second case, there is little (though not quite nothing) you can do: when you use `git fetch` or `git remote update`, you can defer the remote-tracking branch update, or roll it back from your reflog, if new commits contain such a merge.  This will protect *your* repository but will not affect the repository you are fetching from.

For the last case, you can directly protect *your* repository using a pre-receive or update hook.  In this hook you would examine the proposed change to a branch label.  If the label has the form you want protected, you would then scan the commits that would be introduced if the change were accepted.  If any of those are merges that you wish to reject, you can reject the specific update (in the update hook) or the entire set-of-updates (in the pre-receive hook).  As with the `fetch` case, this does not affect the repository that is pushing to you, but if you and your collaborators are using a centralized workflow and you are the center, this will prevent them from introducing such merges to their peers through your (central) repository.